# Changing an input value using the return value after AJAX post of another input value

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to return a value once  I post it using ajax (without submitting the form). However, input value of name=part_name is not changing.

I have a HTML code like below.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<form><table>

<tr><td><b>Part No.</b></td><td><input type="text" list="part_no_name" autocomplete="off" name="part_no" style="width:300px;" value="" placeholder="e.g. 221-55000-41" required>
<datalist id="part_no_name">
<option value="123">123</option>
<option value="124">124</option>
<option value="125">125</option>
</datalist></td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Part Name</b></td><td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="part_name" style="width:300px; border:0;" value=""  readonly></td></tr>

</table></form>
</body></html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[name=part_no]').on('change',function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'live part name.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {part_no:$(this).val()},
                success: function(data){
                    $('input[name=part_name]').val(data);
                }
            });
        });

</script>

</body></html>
```

and live part name.php as below.

*Obviously, I am just stating an example here. Actually, I want it to do a SELECT query on my database using the $_POST['part_no'], and return the result back to HTML at success: function(data).

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_POST['part_no'])){
    $part_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['part_no']);
    echo json_encode($part_no);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your condition in livepartname.php can't work, the value ​passed is $_POST['text'] and not $_POST['part_no']. POST params depends on ajax datas.

Comment: I have edited to `data: {part_no:$(this).val()},`, still not working

Comment: I tried your code and it's working well ... Maybe you can just test your php file with a json_encode('test'); without the rest